# notepad++ regex replace "00" with "01", "02", "03" etc

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++

I have a file which repeats the same code, but now I would like to use Regex to replace the "00" where it is found, but increment each time.

Here is the original file:

```
<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 00</b></li>

<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 00</b></li>

<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 00</b></li>
```

I want to use regex in notepad++ to make it like this :

```
<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 00</b></li>

<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 01</b></li>

<li onclick="tab.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/'" style="text-align: center;"><b>ep 02</b></li>
```

i want to change "ep 00" inside the  tag  to be  ep 01, ep 02, ep 03 ... ep 711 etc ....

Thanks

Comment: That's not exactly a task regex would be used for.

Comment: what can i use to make it Spencer ...

Comment: If i am getting your question right, you want to change text in b tag on click of li element, Right ?

Comment: i am agree with @SpencerWieczorek comment <3

Comment: You could use JavaScript to change the values in a browser with a loop, then copy that part of the source code and replace what you have.

Comment: yes @AkashKOdesia KOdesia

Comment: bare with me please ... how can i do that with js

Comment: <script>
var holderelement=document.body;
var howmanylinksyouwant=3;
for (var i=0;i<howmanylinksyouwant;i++){
var li=document.createElement("li");
li.onclick=function(){location.href="http://stackoverflow.com"}
li.style.textAlign="center";
li.innerHTML="<b>ep "+i+"</b>"
holderelement.append(li);
}
</script>

Comment: Just iterate though the `li` elements with the text `ep 00`, and assign a new value `ep i` where `i` is the current index. [Here is an example in jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/zbdfo6LL/). Note since it seems you wanted 0 padding I added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said before on the comments. Regex is not able of such task ...
you can do though using a calc program ...
OpenOffice Calc
LibreOffice Calc
BrOffice.org Calc
Microsoft Office Excell
you just need to something like [this](http://www.symplebyte.com/microsoft_office/excel/auto_increment.html)

or the js solution

```
var holderelement=document.body;
var howmanylinksyouwant=3;
for (var i=0;i<howmanylinksyouwant;i++){
var li=document.createElement("li");
li.onclick=function(){location.href="stackoverflow.com";}
li.style.textAlign="center";
li.innerHTML="<b>ep "+i+"</b>" holderelement.append(li);
}
```